# Why are my css transitions sometimes keeping the hover state after exiting hover?

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JK9kz/)

CSS transitions have been set up to increase the `transform:scale(x)` property on hover. It works as intended, but sometimes the elements in play will remain at the increased scale value instead of reverting to the original scale value.

It seems that most of the time, everything works correctly when exiting the hover state of an element. However, on some occasions, exiting hover state on an element will cause another element to "snap" to the hover state.

I'm not sure what's causing this, as it seems to happen at random. If you just mouse over the elements at random you will see it almost right away. (/edit/ - try mousing over an element, then exiting DOWN with your mouse. then come back UP into the content area on top of another element. this seems to be the most consistent way to trigger the issue)

Sorry for the ridiculous-looking example - I had to remove what used to be images because the file paths were sensitive.

/edit/ - It seems that the `animation-fill-mode` value of `forwards` was causing this issue, although it is not clear why. Considering that this value is meant to apply to the element its final (100% frame) css values, it doesn't seem like including `forwards` would cause this issue. In fact, it seems like it should correct it.

Does anyone have any input regarding the cause of this issue? Is it exclusive to Chrome or does it persist in other browsers?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Browser-specific?

Comment: Yea, I had problems with IE especially.. and even some with google chrome. When I tried similiar things.

Comment: I am using Chrome v31.0.1650.63 - 

I have increased the hover state's scale property to create a more noticeable effect when this issue exists - 

Try mousing over an element, then mousing DOWN, out of the parent div. Then mouse over a different element within the parent. This issue seems to happen most often when the mouse exits the parent and subsequently hovers over a DIFFERENT element than the previous one.

Comment: Has anyone been able to reproduce this? - I would like to create an effect using only CSS (no javascript/jquery) that expands each image when it is hovered and returns it to its original size when not hovered.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue.  31.0.1650.63 m. Seems also related to the speed of the movement; moving your mouse slowly won't make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's some kind of bug in Chrome.

The problem seems related to the forwards property in the animation; I removed it and the bug seemed to disappear.

It isn't need anyhow since the 100% keyframe is scale (1, 1) opacity (1)

Comment: That's confounding, but hey it works. I don't understand why this is the case, though. W3C defines the `animation-fill-mode` value of `forwards` as: "After the animation ends (determined by animation-iteration-count), the animation will apply the property values for the time the animation ended." Because the css values that you mentioned are the same at the beginning and end of the animation, it shouldn't matter if I use `forwards` or `normal`

Comment: I will gladly mark your answer as the accepted one, I just want to give others a chance to answer the initial question - specifically, it would be great if someone could provide an explanation as to why this error occurs and whether it persists in other browsers

Comment: As you say, it *shouldn't* matter if you use forwards or normal. And this is clearly a bug, so logic doesn't apply here. But, being everything the same, it's always a good idea to make things as simple as posible. And *normal* is simpler than *forwards* (at least for the browser)